# How find the range value $a^2+b^2$ if $\cos{(a\sin{x})}=\sin{(b\cos{x})}$ have no solution

Tags: trigonometry, roots

if the equation  $$\cos{(a\sin{x})}=\sin{(b\cos{x})}$$ have no zero  solution,then 
$a^2+b^2$ range of value

$A:[0,\dfrac{\pi}{4})$,$B: [0,\dfrac{\pi^2}{2})$,$C: [0,\dfrac{\pi^2}{4})$,$D:[0,\dfrac{\pi}{2})$

My try: if the equation have solution ,then 
$$\cos{(a\sin{x})}=\sin{(b\cos{x})}\Longrightarrow \sin{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-a\sin{x}\right)}=\sin{(b\cos{x})}$$
then we have
$$\dfrac{\pi}{2}=a\sin{x}+b\cos{x}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin{(x+\phi)}$$
so
$$a^2+b^2\le\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}$$

But I can't  sure find which is true?

Comment: roots are meant for polynomials. use solutions

Comment: Except for the tiny mistake at the end (the inequality should either point the other way, or it should be strict, if you intended it to be the final solution) and some skipped steps, your approach looks quite fine to me. What more are you looking for?

Comment: @Awesome, the use of the term "roots" to mean solutions to any kind of equations (not just those involving polynomials) is fairly well established.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I don't want to be arguing but see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_(disambiguation)

Comment: @Awesome, I hope you don't think that this is arguing.  I'm merely trying to clear up a misconception that I encounter a lot.  Indeed, your link doesn't say that the only usage of "root" is in regards to polynomials.  In fact it even notes the usage in relation to arbitrary functions.  I quote: "Root of a function, properly called zero of a function, a value of the argument for which the function value is zero."

Comment: @Awesome, We can find such usage of the term in classical texts such as Marden's *Geometry of Polynomials* ([p. 97 in reference to the solutions of eq. 21.5](http://books.google.ca/books?id=ZMYIrr97cQUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA98#v=onepage&q&f=false)) and Boas' *Entire Functions* (pgs. 172 and 217, neither of which are on Google Books unfortunately).

Comment: @AntonioVargas "Properly called zero of a function" tells that sometimes people call zeroes of every function as their roots.

Comment: @Awesome, the adjective "properly" in the above quote is not referring to the fact that the functions aren't polynomials but to the fact that the term "roots" strictly refers to solutions of *equations*.  The phrase "root of f(x)" is less correct than "root of f(x)=0".  This distinction is also observed in Marden and Boas throughout.

Comment: @AntonioVargas What is the difference between root and zero?

Comment: @Awesome, equations have roots, functions have zeros.  A zero of a function $f(x)$ is a root of the equation $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thanks that cleared it up

Comment: @Awesome, no problem :)